# How to get sorted list of nodes for a list of nodes in a NetworkX graph as approximation of TSP

Tags: python, networkx, traveling-salesman

I have an undirected NetworkX graph (not necessarily complete, but connected). Also, I have a list of few nodes from all nodes of the above graph. I want to get the travel distance as per TSP result(or it's approximation).

I tried using **networkx.approximation.traveling_salesman_problem(DS.G, nodes=['A0_S0_R0', 'A0_S14_R4', 'A0_S4_R4', 'A0_S14_R4', 'A0_S14_R4', 'A0_S7_R4'])**, but output list is a list of nodes to be used to cover given nodes in the order they appear in the given input list.

I want either total minimised distance or list of nodes in the order such that travelling distance is minimised and not according to their appearance in the input list.

Comment: Also share how the graph is connected.
If every node is connected to every other node, and no edge weights are provided (1 by default), the solution you mention would basically be an optimal solution

Comment: yeah it is optimal solution. I was not able to interpret the output list properly. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tsp function will return the list of nodes corresponding to best found path.

You can get the minimum distance using

```py
nodes = [...] # list of nodes returned by traveling_salesman_problem()
# assuming you used `weight` key for edge weights
distances = [G.get_edge_data(nodes[i],node[i+1])['weight'] for i in range(len(nodes)-1)]
min_distance = sum(distances)
```